# How to check if a directory exists in ApplescriptObjc

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I know the classic way how to check if a folder exists or not, in AppleScript but is didn't work for me, even if I do the error detection method it dos not work, I found online the Object-C method [fileExistsAtPath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1410277-fileexistsatpath?language=objc) but also don't know how to implement it and I also raid it is not possible, so Please help if you know any solution

my code looks like this for now

```
 on CheckExistence(FileOrFolderToCheckString)
   try
       alias FileOrFolderToCheckString
       return true
   on error
       return false
   end try
end CheckExistence
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppleScriptObjC equivalent is

```
use framework "Foundation"

on CheckExistence(FileOrFolderToCheckString)
   set FileOrFolderToCheckPOSIXPath to POSIX path of FileOrFolderToCheckString
   return (current application's NSFileManager's defaultManager()'s fileExistsAtPath: FileOrFolderToCheckPOSIXPath) as boolean    
end CheckExistence
```